# What are the purpose of checksum and signature in android dex file header?

Tags: android, dalvik, dex

As we know, all android dex file has a dex file header located at the beginning of the dex file which can be described as [DexHeader](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/dalvik/libdex/DexFile.h#216), but why are there checksum and signature, what are the purpose of them? if it's for integrity verification, signature is enough, there is no need for the existence of checksum.

Answer (score 3):

They are both basically different.

Signature is for `Integrity` while Checksum is for `validity`. Hence if a dex file checksum does not match its content then the file is marked as invalid.
[image: Checksum description image]

**Furthermore:** you need to find out [what makes up a dex file `checksum` and `signature` and how is validated](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/dalvik/libdex/DexFile.cpp). If the file `checksum` is invalid there is no essence of checking the integrity of its signature (An error is thrown). The main point of the `signature` is not only for integrity but also to uniquely identify the file;

**For example:** when you optimise a dex file, the size is affected and the checksum value is updated, nevertheless the signature remains constant because the data contained in it is still the same. As you can see they both serve a different purpose; using `the signature` the original dex file can always be tracked and using `the checksum` we can know if the contents of the file is relative to its size whether optimised/un-optimised.

Comment: could you please give me an example or situation that a dex is marked as invalid through checksum checking but still integrated through signature checking?